# Efficient way of creating a new variable via fuzzy string matching and grouped summarization in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to use fuzzy string matching to convert strings to specific ids and perform grouped summarization using dplyr. The basic idea is combining imperfect gene sequences into a single gene name via a dictionary lookup approach and counting how many times the gene is detected. This way, counts for sequences `aaaaaa` and `aaaxaa` match to `gene1` and get added together.

I can do what I want using `for` and `if` statements via a row-by-row comparison of the raw data against the dictionary but I find this will be inefficient when I scale up (raw data files have 15k rows on average, the dictionary has 200 rows). Please see my solution below I'm trying to improve and let me know if you can think of a more efficient and elegant way of doing this.

```r
df <- data.frame(str_var = rep(c("aaaaaa", "aXaaaa", "bbbbbb", "bbbXbb"), 3),
                 grp_var = rep(c("grp1","grp2"), each=6),
                 num_var = rep(c(1,2), 6))

df
#>    str_var grp_var num_var
#> 1   aaaaaa    grp1       1
#> 2   aXaaaa    grp1       2
#> 3   bbbbbb    grp1       1
#> 4   bbbXbb    grp1       2
#> 5   aaaaaa    grp1       1
#> 6   aXaaaa    grp1       2
#> 7   bbbbbb    grp2       1
#> 8   bbbXbb    grp2       2
#> 9   aaaaaa    grp2       1
#> 10  aXaaaa    grp2       2
#> 11  bbbbbb    grp2       1
#> 12  bbbXbb    grp2       2


dictionary <- data.frame(string = c("aaaaaa","bbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd"),
                         id = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4"))

dictionary
#>   string    id
#> 1 aaaaaa gene1
#> 2 bbbbbb gene2
#> 3 cccccc gene3
#> 4 dddddd gene4

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    
    
    for(j in 1:nrow(dictionary)){
        
        match_found <- agrepl(dictionary$string[j], df$str_var[i],
                              max.distance = list(sub=1, ins=0, del=0, all=1-1e-9))
        
        if(match_found == TRUE){
            
            gene = dictionary[j, "id"]
            
            df$gene_id[i] <- gene
            
            break
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

new_df <- df %>%
    group_by(grp_var, gene_id) %>%
    summarize(gene_count=sum(num_var))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'grp_var'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

new_df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   grp_var [2]
#>   grp_var gene_id gene_count
#>   <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 grp1    gene1            6
#> 2 grp1    gene2            3
#> 3 grp2    gene1            3
#> 4 grp2    gene2            6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The data sounds small enough that you could do a cartesian join to get a 15k x 200 = 3M row dataset and then filter for best matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps a `fuzzyjoin` would be more easier

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_left_join(df, dictionary, by = c("str_var" = "string")) %>% 
     group_by(grp_var, gene_id = id) %>% 
     summarise(gene_count = sum(num_var), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  grp_var gene_id gene_count
  <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>
1 grp1    gene1            6
2 grp1    gene2            3
3 grp2    gene1            3
4 grp2    gene2            6
```

Comment: Holy moly! This is beautiful! I mean wow! Would this still be efficient if I had a lot larger data frames and dictionaries? I was thinking maybe a `data.table` edit-in-place approach may be more efficient but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Atakan i haven't tested on big data, but it should be faster than your nested loop

Comment: Would you be able to comment on how I can get the partial matching work here if the dictionary was something like `aaaaaa` and the target was something like `XXXaaaXaaXXX` (unequal lengths also involving a substitution). This solution results in `NA`columns upon merging. I'm suspecting that match constraints of the underlying `stringdist` package is resulting in failure

Comment: @Atakan with `stringdist_left_join`, there are options with `method` By default, i think it is selecting `osa`,  You could change that method along with `max_dist` for some methods to relax the matching rules. `method = c("osa", "lv", "dl", "hamming", "lcs", "qgram", "cosine", "jaccard", "jw",
    "soundex")`

Comment: @Atakan Also, you could use `regex_left_join` with `match_fun` as `str_detect`

Comment: @Atakan with your example data, `fuzzy_left_join(df, dictionary, by = c("str_var" = "string"), match_fun = str_detect) %>% fill(id) %>% group_by(grp_var, gene_id = id) %>% summarise(gene_count = sum(num_var), .groups = 'drop')` also worked

Comment: (I realize my comment is getting a little bit out of the scope of the initial question) The new solution you provided works for perfect matches in the substring. Can it be tweaked to allow imperfect matches in a stretch of 20 characters or so?

Comment: @Atakan i think with distance matches there won't be a perfect solution.  One option is to try on different `method` and then merge all of them.  Or if the number of mismatches are minimal, then could manually correct it